# Android getString method

Tags: android, string

i'm trying to concatenate a String value setted into `string.xml` with a date using this code:

```
holder.time.setText(date.getHours()+" " + getString(R.string.ore));
```

but i recive error: can not resolve method.
I have try to this code:

```
holder.time.setText(date.getHours()+" " +R.string.ore);
```

works but the value `R.string.ore` is retrieved as int value and not string, but i need a string value
I need to use the value by `string.xml` and not using a simple string example "ore"

Any help?

Comment: Try it as: `getResources().getString(R.string.ore)`

Comment: This should work anywhere: `holder.time.getContext().getString(R.string.ore)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in an `activity`'s context, use this:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.ore);
```

If you're in a `fragment`'s context, use this:

```
getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.ore);
```

If you're within an `adapter`, you need to pass the container activity's context to it via the adapter's constructor.

```
// When creating the adapter, pass the activity's context
// keeping in mind the notes above
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(this, ...);
```

And from within the adapter:

```
private Context mContext; // A member variable of the adapter class

public YourAdapter(Context context, ...) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Then you can get your string resource this way:

```
mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.ore);
```

Comment: It looks like he is in an `adapter`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows you're right, I will update my answer.

Comment: If you are using an adapter, you should already have access to `context`.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Hello can you take a look at this answer and let me know if you know what happens please [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838974/google-place-api-place-searcher)

Answer (score 2):

`getString` is a method of `Context`. If can't resolve it, it means that your class is not a subclass of `Context`. You could use

```
holder.time.getContext()
```

to retrieve the `Context` you used to inflate that `TextView` and access `getString()`. Eg `holder.time.getContext().getString(R.string.hour)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
holder.time.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" " +getString(R.string.ore));
```

This may help you.